# Can Android Studio use the system CMake?

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I'm using Android Studio + CMake to build a native library. AS requested installing CMake, even though I already have CMake installed and in my path. Can you tell AS to look for CMake at a certain location, instead of installing another CMake?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question, I can't find any way to add the system cmake path, as well as LLDB, to AS-v2.2.3

Comment: Me too. Although it seems we depend hopelessly on further development of Android Studio that uses (and needs) a handmade fork of an older CMake version, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new Android plugin for gradle 3.0 will support [using system CMake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#vanilla_cmake), for CMake 3.7+.

From that webpage:

> 2. Download and install CMake 3.7 or higher from the official CMake website.
> 3. Include the path to the CMake installation in your project's local.properties file:
>
>    cmake.dir="path-to-cmake"

Comment: Just FYI to future others, don't include `bin` in the path to CMake (e.g. `cmake.dir=C\:\\Program Files\\CMake`). You can debug this by looking at your idea.log.

Comment: Android Studio 3.2.1 I also needed to download ninja.exe and copy it in the cmake bin folder.

Comment: @JacobBlock omg I've wasted probably 1-2 hours and given up several times trying to use a modern version of CMake, your comment just solved all my problems.  With that in mind I suppose the docs "Point to a CMake installation" could make sense?  but the example is always `cmake.dir=/path-to-cmake`

Comment: The default install dir in linux is /usr/local/bin/cmake - I had to make cmake.dir=/usr/local/ because andrroid studio adds /bin/cmake to the end of it...