# Path to cmake in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

When building my Android project in AndroidStudio 3.6.1 I'm getting an error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe''
```

cmake is correctly installed but `myusername` does not exists. Instead, it should be a different folder.

Where can I change the path?

Comment: It looks like you can set `cmake.dir=<path-to-cmake>` in the `local.properties` file for your project. Instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#vanilla_cmake). Also, perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596679/3987854) is useful.

Comment: @squareskittles I added in the local.properties the path to cmake but now I'm getting the error "Could not get version from cmake.dir path 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe'." But this path exists.

Comment: @squareskittles New error message is now "Actual CMake version '3.6.0' did not satisfy requested minimum or default CMake minimum version '3.10.2'. Possibly cmake.dir doesn't match android.externalNativeBuild.cmake.version."

Comment: The documentation I linked before also shows how to set the CMake version, which should help you avoid these issues.